# Multiple coordinates from one mysql entry to use in polylines google maps

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

Hi there i need to know if there is a way to separate coordinates that i have retrieved from a mysql database to use on the google maps polylines  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

they are currently stored like this

```
(x, y)(x, y)(x, y)
```

As the number of coordinates vary each time as it depends how long the user logs the coordinate data for. however i dont know how to separe the coordinates to enter in to the code like this:

```
var polyCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
    new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
    new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)
  ];
```

I retrieve the data like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "new google.maps.LatLng(" . $row['coordinate'] . "),";
}
```

Comment: So that you want to do, is to split string like _(2, 30), (6, 1), (8, 7)_ to pairs of x and y like x = 2 and y = 30, and then call _new google.maps.LatLng(2, 30)_. Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly what i want to do. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you need to do is to split the String gotten from database by certain characters. In PHP that function is called [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

So first you need to strip some characters from the initial string to make it more easy to handle on next phase. What we want to take out is the starting ( and ending ) of whole row. This can be done with [substr](http://php.net/substr) and [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) (returns length) commands like this

```
$coordinates = $row['coordinate'];
$coordinates = explode("(", $coordinates)[1];
$coordinates = substr($coordinates, 1, strlen($coordinates) - 2);
// $coordinates is now "x,y)(x,y)(x,y"
```

Now "explode" this based on string ")(" to leave only the "x,y" pairs

```
$pieces = explode(")(", $coordinates);
```

after that $pieces is array containing the following items (Strings)

```
$pieces[0] is "x, y" // First pair
$pieces[1] is "x, y" // Second pair
$pieces[2] is "x, y" // Third pair
```

Now that we have all those available, we can iterate through them to call your initial function *new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)* like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($pieces); ++$i) {
    // Here you could also use the $pieces[$i] straight away since it is now always pair like "x,y"
    $coords = explode(",", $pieces[$i]);
    $x = $coords[0];
    $y = $coords[1];
    echo("new google.maps.LatLng(" . $x . "," . $y . ")");
    if ($i + 1 < strlen($pieces)) {// If this isn't last row
        echo(",\n"); // Print comma
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is something off with my answer, haven't written PHP for years :)

Comment: Make sure to familiarize yourself with the concepts of handling the strings instead of just copy-pasting the code. That will pay back eventually! :)